# In this insertion sort algorithm for example, how would I prove the algorithm's time complexity is O(n^2)?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Take the following insertion sort algorithm:

[image]

I know it's O(n^2) fairly easy by examining it. But as far as *proving* it's O(n^2), how would I go about doing that? I could add up all the operations, but `n + "sum of j=2 to n"` wouldn't really result in n^2 as far as I know.

I don't really see how to prove this exactly. Could someone try to clearly explain how I would prove this, in a way that would work for an O(n^3) algorithm as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prove big O complexity by considering how many operations are performed in the **worst case**. You've done the counting part and entered the results in the right hand column of your image, so what remains to be proven is that the dominant term is `O(n^2)`.

Apart from the terms that involve the sum, your program consists of instructions that get executed `n-1` times so these are all `O(n)` terms.

Now for the terms with the sum. In the worst case a `t_j` can be `j` because you may end up decrementing `i` which you set to `j` all the way down to 0. So in this worst case we have `t_j = j` and then you have a term with a `sum from 2 to n of j` which is `O(n^2)`. This is due to following the mathematical identity:

[image]

This can be proven by summing two of these series together, paying attention so that you add two terms that sum to `n+1` together, and then dividing the sum by two. Have a look at the [proof in wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html).

Finally, since `O((n^2 + n)/2) = O(n^2)` you get that the terms that include the sum dominate the runtime and that is why the algorithm is `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 2):

It's O(n^2) because you've got a multiplication, not a sum.
Take by example, an array sorted in inverse order:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

In these cases every iteration of the inner loop will scan and shift the entire sorted subsection of the array before inserting the next element. This gives insertion sort a quadratic running time (i.e., O(n2)).

[More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Best.2C_worst.2C_and_average_cases)

The best way to understand the complexity is trying to find the worst case example and following the algorithm's steps.

Answer (score -2):

**Assumption 1**: If a procedure P is run no more than T times, and P runs in O(f(N)) each time, then the overall runtime is O(T*f(N))

**Assumption 2**: If a procedure P is run in O(f(N)) time, and a procedure Q runs in O(g(N)) time, then running P followed by Q requires O(f(N) + g(N)) time.

To be pedantic, assumption 1 follows from assumption 2 if you prefer.

**Assumption 3**: Assignments and arithmetic are O(1) operations.

Combine these three assumptions, you get your result.

Lines 6 and 7 run in O(1) and O(1) time respectively, so together they run in O(1 + 1) = O(1) time. (By Assumption 3 and 2)

Line 5 determines that {6,7} will run no more than A.Length - 0 times, so the runtime of {5,6,7} is O(A.Length * 1) = O(A.Length)    (By Assumption 1)

Lines 2, 4, and 8 run in O(1) time, so {2,4,5,6,7,8} run in O(1 + 1 + A.Length + 1) = O(A.Length)time. (By assumption 3 and 2 again)

Line 1 determines that {2..8} will run no more than A.Length times, so the runtime for lines {1..8} is O(A.Length * A.Length) = O(A.Length ^2)   (by Assumption 1).